# Why is this pattern search hanging?

Tags: regex, linux, grep, base64

I am running Linux CentOs and i am trying to find some malicious code in my wordpress installation with this command:

```
grep -r 'php \$[a-zA-Z]*=.as.;' * |awk -F : '{print $1}'
```

When I hit enter, the process just hangs...I want to double check that I have the syntax right and all I have to do is wait?

How Can I get some sort of feedback/something happening while its searching?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: `awk -F : '{print $1}'` seems like an.... interesting(?) hack to get either `grep -l` or `grep -h`?

Answer (score 1):

Its probably taking its time due to the `-r *` (recursively, all files/dirs)?

Consider

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0trn10 grep -l 'php \$[a-zA-Z]*=.as.;'
```

which will process the files in batches of (max) 10, and printing those commands as it goes.

Of course, like that you can probably optimize the heck out of it, with a simple measure like

```
find -type f -iname '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0trn10 grep -l 'php \$[a-zA-Z]*=.as.;'
```

---

Kind of related:

You can do similar things without find for smaller trees, with recent bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -l 'pattern' **/*.php
```

Comment: Thanks!...But what exactly does the first command print out? I see a tonne of lines lol...

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: **1.** just read that with `find -type f | less -SR`; now, **2.** it _is_ a lot of lines, but no more than your command was traversing! Try `grep -lr '.?' *` for fun... See why it was slow?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `grep -r` to recursively grep, one option is to use `find` to get the list of filenames, and feed them to `grep` one at a time. That lets you add other commands alongside the grep, such as `echo`s. For example, you could create a script called `is-it-malware.sh` that contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep 'php \$[a-zA-Z]*=.as.;' "$1" >/dev/null
then
    "!!! $1 is malware!!!"
else
    "    $1 is fine."
fi
```

and run this command:

```
find -type f -exec ./is-it-malware.sh '{}' ';'
```

to run your script over every file in the current directory and all of its subdirectories (recursively).